# Why i can't fix my manifest.json matches in content_scripts

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

I got an error with this text:

**Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Empty path.**

I don't know why it didn't work so I tried to change it to this:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
    "matches": ["https://rotwo.bubbleapps.io"],
    "json": ["manifest.json"]
} ]
```

Comment: Add `/*` after the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You should write :

```
"content_scripts": [ {
    "matches": ["https://rotwo.bubbleapps.io/*"],
    "json": ["manifest.json"]
} ]
```